# How to design e-commerce database for a product which has an option what time to get

Tags: database-design

I'm designing an e-commerce website.

It has a product that have options to choose for a customer.

the options that a customer can select are what time to receive the product today.

```
-------------
|    11:00   | <-- select box on product page on website
-------------
|    15:00   |
-------------
|    18:00   |
-------------
```

So I want to create a product with options

1. 11 o'clock for Monday and Thursday
2. 3 o'clock for Everyday
3. 6 o'clock for Tuesday and Friday

What I have done so far with this idea is

```
-------------      ---------------------     --------------------
|   product  |     | product_schedule   |   |product_days_of_week|
-------------      ---------------------     --------------------
|    id      |     |    allow_time      |   |    day_of_week     |
-------------      ---------------------     --------------------
|    name    |     |     product_id     |   | product_schedule_id|
-------------      ---------------------     --------------------
```

Is there any better design for this purpose?
Thanks

Comment: use a calendaring solution maybe.

Comment: @danblack what do you mean calendaring solution?

Comment: rather than storing times in a database, use a calendar server like [radicale](https://radicale.org/) to store the product. Then the client has an already built calendar inteface see see the delivery time. Use caldav in your e-commence code to manipulate times.

Comment: @danblack I will check this out. Thanks for commenting